# How I type @ with a Latin American keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, special-characters

I used to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> in Windows. I think I tried every combination in Ubuntu and @ doesn't appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to press <kbd>ALTGR</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to get the @

Comment: And actually this is the same for Windows 7. In XP it was ALTGR+2